# verificar se tem virgula e apagar uma virgula se tiver na string pelo Ruby

Tags: ruby

oi como eu faço para apagar para verificar se a ultima palavra da variavel com string é virgula e se for como faço para apagar essa virgula no fim da variavel string tipo

teste = "meu nome é neymar,"

depois deixar 
teste = "meu nome é neymar"

Em codigo Ruby eu preciso

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o método [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-sub) que substitui a primeira ocorrência de uma string ou padrão:

```
"meu nome é neymar,".sub(/,\z/, '')
 => "meu nome é neymar"
"substitui so a , do final,".sub(/,\z/, '')
 => "substitui so a , do final"
```

`\z` é o padrão para final da string, então `/,\z/` é o padrão para uma vírgula seguida do final da string. `.sub(/,\z/, '')`, portanto, substitui uma virgula no final da string por "nada" - ou seja, remove a vírgula no final da linha, mas não as vírgulas que estejam em outras partes do texto.

Comment: Insira comentários. Explique PORQUE esse código atende a pergunta e qual é o retorno disso. O que o `sub()` está fazendo com os dados?

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar o método [`String#delete`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/delete).

```
'Essa é uma string de testes, ok?'.delete(',')
=> 'Essa é uma string de testes ok?'
```

O legal desse método é que você pode escrever algumas expressões. Supondo que eu queira retirar tudo o que não for números de uma string:

```
'+55 41 9 9182-8217'.delete('^0-9')
=> "5541991828217"
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, basicamente eu faria assim

```
def remove_last_character(text, character)
  string_to_array = text.split("")
  string_to_array.pop if string_to_array.last == character
  string_to_array.join("")
end

remove_last_character("meu nome, é neymar,", ",")
```

Resultado:

```
2.5.0 :026 > remove_last_character("meu nome, é neymar,", ",")
 => "meu nome, é neymar"
```